# Display dataset in datagrid?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, dataset

I have tried googling so much that I have given up trying to look.

I am trying to display a dataset in a wpf datagrid. After that I am going to need to display the individual column value in textboxes. I can then change the value in those textboxes and pressing, say, a commit button, to commit the changes to a database. Here's the code I have so far.

`
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim dbConnString As String
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim sqlStatement As String

```
    dbConnString = "Data Source=SG2;Initial Catalog=RovisysAsiaITAssets;User ID=sa;Password=Rovisys2012"
    con.ConnectionString = dbConnString
    con.Open()

    sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM TabletInventory"
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlStatement, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "TabletInventory")
```

`

can anybody help me? Even a pointer to a reading would be fine. Thanks!

Comment: try reading this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples

Answer (score 0):

```
Your xaml code should look like something like this.

<DataGrid Name="DataGrid1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TabletInventory}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

Code behind

```
dbConnString = "Data Source=SG2;Initial Catalog=RovisysAsiaITAssets;User ID=sa;Password=Rovisys2012"
    con.ConnectionString = dbConnString
    con.Open()
    sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM TabletInventory"
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlStatement, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "TabletInventory")
    DataGrid1.DataContext = ds;
```